# how to print the original encoded string for serial programming in python?

Tags: python, string, serial-port

My question is simple, i have a string like "\x55"

if I do

```
print "\x55"
```

Python will print is as

```
U
```

What I want is printing "\x55".xxxx and the result should be its original form "\x55", how can I do this ?

More specifically,

```
>>> a = '"\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00&'
>>> a
'"\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00&'
>>> print a
"&
```

but what I wanted is when somehow

```
>>> print somebuild-infunction(a) #maybe a.noencoding()
```

returns

```
\x22\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x26
```

**Update:**

I don't know why I got downvote, but still I wish to share the following I just wrote.
I need these tool functions in my serial devices class, so I can simply use serial.write() to send commands to my devices.

**`And I found a bug in python, that is even you commented out '\x', the interpreter still considers it as a ValueError: wrong escape of '\x', so I added '\' in the comments.`**

```
def hex2str(src, zeropad = 2):
    """
    convert hex number 0x55 to '0x55', 0x1 to '0x01', with zero pad.
    """
    return '0x' + hex(src)[2:].zfill(zeropad)

def hex2bytestring(src):
    """
    convert 0x55 to \\x55
    """
    return chr(int(hex(src),16))

def bytestring2hex(src):
    """
    convert \\x55 into int (not '0x55' but 85)
    """
    return int(src.encode('hex'),16)

def list2bytestr(src):
    """
    convert [0x55, 0x01 ...] to "\\x55\\x01..."
    """
    return ''.join([hex2bytestring(x) for x in src])

def bytestr2list(src):
    """
    reverse of list2bytestr
    """
    return [int(ch.encode('hex'),16) for ch in src]

def dispbytestr(src):
    """
    src is byte string like '\\x55\\x01'
    print byte string as the original encoded format.
    But this output is not actually the byte string, instead, it is the raw string.

    Alternative:
    print ''.join(r'\\x' + ch.encode('hex') for ch in src)
    """
    print ''.join(r'\x%02X' % ord(ch) for ch in src )
```

Comment: Do you *really* want the opening and trailing single-quote marks in the output of `print`?

Comment: 1) Python includes an "**interpreter**", not an "interrupter". 2) `"""` defines a string, not a comment. `#` is the comment character, and `# \x55` is perfectly legal. 3) If you want to disable `\ `-interpretation in the string, precede the string with `r`, like so: `r""" hello \x55"""`

Comment: I don't know why you got a downvote, but I voted to close, because the question as written doesn't make any sense. You're asking how to get "the original encoded format" out of the bytes from your serial device. The `U` character _is_ the original encoded format. There is no string with the characters `\x55` to "recover". If you want to generate such a string, of course you can do so; you can generate any string you want. But the premise that you had such a thing at some point and need to get it back is wrong, and the entire original question about `print "\x55"` is at best misleading.

Comment: I also have no idea why someone went and downvoted every answer on the page. I assume it's because someone doesn't like it when people answer bad questions. I've deleted my answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is based on premises that are not true and make no sense, so there is no way to answer it as written.

Comment: Original is the relative term, for my serial case, \x55 is the original, 'U' is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can format the string to have precisely the characters you want.

```
>>> a = '"\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00&'
>>> print ''.join(r'\x%02X'%ord(ch) for ch in a)
\x22\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x26
>>>
```

`%02X` formats a integer value into its two-digit hexadecimal representation.

`ord(ch)` converts a single-character string into its integer value.

`for ch in a` separates the string `a` into its individual characters.

`''.join(...)` concatenates a set of strings into a single string.

Comment: Thanks this is what I wanted. But is there a simpler solution than this ?

Comment: I got it. I meant, print ''.join(r'\x' + ch.encode('hex') for ch in input) .

Comment: plz don't downvote both of the right answers from Rob and Electron.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an extra slash:

```
print "\\x55"
```

If you can't edit the string, try this:

```
print hex(ord("\x55"))
# "0x55"
# This will still be stored a a hexadecimal answer
# Put str() around it to make it a string
```

Or a longer version based on the previous answer:

```
print "".join(["\\x",str(hex(ord("\x55")))[2::]])
# "\x55"
# This will be stored a a string on the other hand
```

Or if you are working with a line of input, try this:

```
def hex_to_string(lst):
    temp = []
    for v in lst:
        s = str(hex(ord(v)))
        temp.append("".join(["\\x","0"*(4-len(s)),s[2::]]))
    return "".join(temp)
```

Comment: Thanks , but it's not what I am expecting, what if I got tons of '\x', it should be an encoding/decoding syntax problem.

Comment: @tomriddle_1234, This may help: `print hex(ord("\x55"))`, but it will output the answer as `0x55`. Or a longer version: `print "".join(["\\x",str(hex(ord("\x55")))[2::]])` which will output it the way you want it.

Comment: I'm sorry, this would only work on '\x', it doesn't recover '"\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00&' to '\x22\x01\x01\x02\x00\x00\x00\x26'

Comment: Look at my new edit, I defined a function that will do that. It doesn't use complex python methods, but it works.

Comment: If you decide to use my code, you can change the function name, and then you will have to call it with the name you wanted like in my example `print hex_to_string("hexadecimal line")`. I also added a "shorter" version

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the string as a raw string:

```
>>> t = r"\x55"
>>> print t
\x55
```